# how to check if something has been written into file?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I have a rather tricky question

Is there a way to check if something has been written into a file?

---

This is a piece of code written by [Eric Petroelje](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65070/eric-petroelje), and I need to check if the "Hello world" has been written into a file.

This would be useful for checking if a big number is written to a text file.
Thank you in advance!

```
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "Hello world";
        BufferedWriter output = null;
        try {
            File file = new File("example.txt");
            output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            output.write(text);
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
          if ( output != null ) {
            output.close();
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the file after having written it? But I don't get the point, if the write operation is successful, the content IS the thing you've just written.

Comment: If you want to make sure the data has been written out to the OS, flush. If you want to make sure it's been fully committed to long term storage, sync.

Comment: Have you checked out [Watching a Directory for Changes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Read the file after having written it

```
public boolean writeToTXT(String text, String path)
{
    BufferedWriter output = null;
    try {
        File file = new File(path);
        output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        output.write(text);
        output.flush();
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
          if ( output != null ) {
            output.close();
          }
        }
        
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = br.readLine();

    while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
        line = br.readLine();
    }
    return sb.toString().equals(text); }
}
```